# Focus Mode in UITextView

Tags: swift, string, uitextview

Can you help me how to make something like Focus mode on iA Writer app? While typing, everything is blurred except the sentence you are writing

Is there a simple way to get the range of the sentence at selected range in UITextView? Something like `.paragraphRange`. I tried with `.lineRange` but it returns the range of the paragraph also.

```
let sentenceRange = composeText.lineRange(for: TextView.selectedRange)
```

If I want to focus the paragraph, it works fine, either with .lineRange or .paragraphRange

```
    if (focus)
{
   if let stringLength = noteTextView.text?.characters.count
   {
        // Defocus everything
        noteTextView.textStorage.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: styles.titleTextColor().withAlphaComponent(0.10), range:NSMakeRange(0, stringLength))

         let sentenceRange = composeText.lineRange(for: noteTextView.selectedRange)

            // Focus 
    noteTextView.textStorage.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: styles.titleTextColor().withAlphaComponent(1), range: sentenceRange)

 }
```

}

But when I try to find the right sentence, it makes some mistakes.

```
if (focus)
    {
        if let stringLength = noteTextView.text?.characters.count
        {
            // Defocus Everything
            noteTextView.textStorage.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: styles.titleTextColor().withAlphaComponent(0.10), range:NSMakeRange(0, stringLength))

            // Find the Sentence to focus

            var arr = [String]()

            noteTextView.text.enumerateSubstrings(in: (noteTextView.text.range(of: noteTextView.text))!, options: NSString.EnumerationOptions.bySentences,
                                                  { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, bool) -> () in arr.append(substring!)

            })

            let selectedRange = noteTextView.selectedRange
            var counted : Int = 0
            var focusSentence : String = ""
            var found : Bool = false
            var i : Int = 0

            while(found == false)
            {
                counted += arr[i].characters.count

                if(counted >= selectedRange.location-1)
                {
                    found = true
                    focusSentence = arr[i]
                    counted -= arr[i].characters.count
                }
                else
                {
                    i += 1
                }
            }


            let range = NSMakeRange(counted, focusSentence.characters.count

            noteTextView.textStorage.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: styles.titleTextColor().withAlphaComponent(1), range: range)
        }
    }
```

Right now, I'm trying with this, but it doesn't work when I change the cursor position.

```
 if(focus)
    {

        if(x)
        {
            if let stringLength = noteTextView.text?.characters.count
            {
                // Defocus Everything
                noteTextView.textStorage.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: styles.titleTextColor().withAlphaComponent(0.1), range:NSMakeRange(0, stringLength))
                x = false
            }
        }

        if(text == "." || text == "!" || text == “?”)
        {
            x = true
        }
        else
        {
            self.noteTextView.typingAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : styles.bodyWriterColor().withAlphaComponent(1)]

        }

    }
```

Comment: post your code pls

Comment: @DanielLegler please check

Comment: guys? Anyone? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Did anyone get a complete solution to the focus mode piece? I know this is an older post but would love to see a solution follow up if there is one. Thanks!